# wso2is OpenId Connect ignore post_logout_redirect_uri

Tags: openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to log out of my application configured with OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration. 
I use the url https://myserver:9443/oidc/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https://liferay/c/portal/logout&id_token_hint=. 
The logout is done correctly but the redirect url is ignored. 
There is something wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check their documentation ? https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/OpenID+Connect+Logout+URL+Redirection

Comment: yes I did. Maybe I can not recover the token id in liferay. Can you help me?